# Why $b^2-4ac$ as determinant?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I am curious why $b^2-4ac$ is used as a determinant of a conic section?

Like why this specific expression is chosen, why the value is always greater, lesser or equal to zero for hyperbola, ellipse and parabola and how does the value prove the type of conic section.

A detailed answer would be of real help.

Comment: Hint: $b^2-4ac$ is the discriminant of a quadratic polynomial, and conics are the sets of solutions to a quadratic polynomial in two variables.

Comment: How is b2−4ac the discriminant of a quadratic polynomial?

Comment: The solution to a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  The sign of $b^2-4ac$ determines how many solutions there are to the equation.  If it is less than 0, there are no (real) solutions, if it equals zero, then there is exactly one solution, and if it is greater than 0, there are two solutions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply. Please forgive me for being so dumb. But how does that help in determining the type of conic section?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Comment: Dear @Hayden : That all seems relevant to finding how many $x$-intercepts there are, but that count alone does not tell you what the type of conic is. The thing is that we're not examining a quadratic polynomial, but rather a homogenous polynomial of degree 2 in variables $x,y$.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a conic
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=d$$ then you can complete the square,

$$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}y\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}y^2=d$$
or

$$4a^2\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}y\right)^2-Dy^2=4ad$$

Since $a^2$ is positive we see that the form of the conic is determined by the sign of $D$.

Comment: Perfectly answers my question! Thank you.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus Since the general equation of a conic is $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F =0$ , may I ask why you only took $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$ to complete the square? Why is the $Dx + Ey + F =0$ ignored or eliminated? Thanks in advance